# This one should be popular!

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay

#### My first attempt:

> One was a star.
>   The best was bested.
>   One drove a car.
>   One only rested.
>
> One made art.
>   With stones they vied.
>   But then they did part.
>   And half of them died.
>
> 31 was a cop.
>   Mustard's bank was his nose.
>   They rose to the top.
>   As your matriarch knows.
>
> Of the last two,
>   One is amazed.
>   The other sells shoes.
>   The youth were all crazed.
>
> They all shared a liver.
>   They spoke of her love.
>   Iron met river.
>   And villainous glove.
>
> A lane full of sights.
>   The town had a pool.
>   Three members, one knight.
>   A silvery tool.
>
> Fabulous number.
>   A half dozen cried.
>   Eyes gilded in slumber.
>   We heard of a slide.
>
> A teacher was killed.
>   And broken wings flew.
>   A door was filled.
>   And you're wealthy too.
>
> An apartment was burned.
>   Or so it was said.
>   Because a lover was spurned.
>   With a drain in his bed.

#### So far as I have seen, most puzzles like this require a line by line explanation, so that is expected here as well.  Enjoy!

*Note:  I have been made aware that there were a couple of errors in the original post (which have now been corrected) - one was due to autocorrect and a failure to proof read, the other was a total brainfart on my part.  Sorry.  I will use proper diligence next time.*

Comment: I'm already working on part two.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The theme is

> The Beatles

One was a star.
 The best was bested.
 One drove a car.
 One only rested.

> Ringo **Starr**. Pete **Best** was replaced. Either *Drive My Car* (vvye) or *Day Tripper* (**Sunday driver, yeah**). While there is a lot of sleeping in Beatles songs, *I'm Only Sleeping* (vvye) also includes "only".

One made art.
 With stones they vied.
 But then they did part.
 And half of them died.

> Stuart Sutcliffe, original bassist, left to be **an artist** (A E),  They were a group at the same time as the **Rolling Stones**, then they **broke up** and now **two of the four** (Harrison and Lennon) are **dead**

31 was a cop.
 Mustard's bank was his nose.
 They rose to the top.
 As your matriarch knows.

> In Maxwell's Silver Hammer, "**P.C. 31** said we caught a dirty one." (Irishpanda) - PC for Police Constable, or cop, *Mean Mr Mustard* "**Keeps a ten-bob note up his nose**", the Beatles were the top band by any measure, and *Your Mother Should Know*

Of the last two,
 One is amazed.
 The other sells shoes.
 The youth were all crazed.

> This is Paul McCartney, who sang *Maybe I'm Amazed*, and Ringo Starr, who now has a line of shoes (among other things). The last line is Beatlemania (A E)

They all shared a liver.
 They spoke of her love.
 Iron met river.
 And villainous glove.

> pun on **Liverpool** where they were from (histocrat), *She Loves You* (A E), Liverpool's Cast Iron Shore mentioned in Glass Onion (Irishpanda), in *Yellow Submarine* [bad guy's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_Blue_Meanie) fiercest weapon was "The Dreadful Flying Glove"

A lane full of sights.
 The town had a pool.
 Three members, one knight.
 A silvery tool.

> *Penny Lane*, pun on **Liverpool** where they were from, all four were awarded MBE but John returned his, Paul was knighted, and *Maxwell's Silver Hammer*

Fabulous number.
 A half dozen cried.
 Eyes gilded in slumber.
 We heard of a slide.

> "Fab Four", though there's plenty of weeping, in *While My Guitar Gently Weeps* (A E) the six strings of the guitar can be the half dozen, *Golden Slumbers*, and *Helter Skelter*

A teacher was killed.
 And broken wings flew.
 A door was filled.
 And you're wealthy too.

> *Maxwell's Silver Hammer* is about a teacher being killed (Fillet), a line in *Blackbird* is **take these broken wings and learn to fly**, in *Fixing A Hole*: "I'm filling the cracks that ran through the door" (Irishpanda), *Baby, You're a Rich Man*.

An apartment was burned.
 Or so it was said.
 Because a lover was spurned.
 With a drain in his bed.

> *Norwegian Wood (This Bird Has Flown)*. "I crawled off to sleep in the bath" and "I lit a fire."

Comment: "One drove a car" could be referring to "Drive my car", written by Paul McCartney, just like "One only rested" could be "I'm only sleeping" by John Lennon. (Also, if I recall correctly, his name is Pete Best, not George.)

Comment: The penultimate verse could be Maxwell's Silver Hammer (teacher killed), Blackbird (take these broken wings and learn to fly), ???, Baby You're a Rich man.

Comment: They all shared (pooled?) a liver = they all came from Liverpool

Comment: @Fillet the last two I got before seeing the comment, MSH is in another clue too, but maybe there are dupes

Comment: @histocrat perhaps Liverpool is also the answer to "the town had a pool"

Comment: "31 was a cop": Verse 3, line 1 of I Am the Walrus refers to a policeman (bit of a stretch). As for "three are knights", only Paul was actually knighted, HOWEVER, all 4 received the MBE, with John returning his.

Comment: "One" is a clue in itself, there is an album called "One". Immediately came to mind after reading the first verse of this riddle.

Comment: "I dig a pygmy, phase one in which....."

Comment: "A Dorris was filled" : At the beginning of Two of Us, John shouts "'I Dig a Pygmy', by Charles Hawtrey and the Deaf Aids... Phase One, in which **Doris gets her oats!**"

Comment: Lennon attended an art college and made drawings and lithographs.

Comment: It was just some random thing John shouted at the beginning of the recording for that song.

Comment: One made art = Stuart Sutcliffe? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuart_Sutcliffe

Comment: The "31 was a cop" line refers to Maxwell's Silver Hammer: "P.C. 31 said 'We caught a dirty one.'"

Comment: Might the OP be missing the distinction between MBE and knighthood? It would fit if you consider all 4 were made MBE, minus the 1 returned by John, leaving 3.

Comment: Excellent.  "Dorris" was my autocorrect's mangling of "door".  "Three are knights" is an error on my part.  Three are MBEs, one is a knight.  My bad.

Comment: @Irishpanda - Exactly.  I'm sorry - I know knights and MBEs are different, but I was tired when I posted this and my brain farted.

Comment: I edited to fix the goof, since the answer is already obvious.

Comment: **One of your lines is still incorrect**

Comment: Glass Onion : "standing on the cast iron shore"

Comment: @Irishpanda You're right! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cast_Iron_Shore

Comment: Fixing A Hole : "I'm filling the cracks that ran through the door"

Comment: Well done overall, even if there were a couple of goofs! I'm liking this kind of puzzle a lot, it's like a collaborative scavenger hunt.

Comment: @Irishpanda - Thanks!  You all did a brilliant job, especially Kate, but also yourself and AE, and everyone else who contributed.

Comment: The "Doris gets her oats" idea was an ingenious way to make sense of an error too.

Comment: Technically, the fabulous number was 4 (fab four), but I'll let it slide, since I didn't notice it before.

Comment: I also just noticed that the art reference is still missing.  AE nailed it in the comments above.

Comment: @KateGregory - What gave you the first inkling that I was thinking of The Beatles?

Comment: The final verse. It was so obviously Norwegian Wood. My first version of the answer just had that stanza and said the theme was Beatles *songs*. Then I started to tackle the other lines and realized it also included the members. For someone of a certain age, who has the albums, it was relatively straightforward after that.